# Access Lightning bundle of standard app

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am curious to know whether possible to see the lightning components/bundles associated with sales app?

Comment: Do you mean the lightning experience/s1 mobile application, and all those components?

Comment: Only lightning components..

Comment: Lightning Experience is 100% lightning components. S1 mobile is mostly lightning components with a thin native wrapper for some small features. That's what you want to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the core aura framework which could be thought of as the foundation of Lightning Components and by extension the foundation of S1 mobile and Lightning Experience, the application level components that comprise these applications are not published as open source software.

The [Aura](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura) open source project can be found in the [Salesforce R&D](https://github.com/forcedotcom) github account.

Less well known perhaps is there was a small reference app created to support the open source project called [aura-note](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura-note). This is also a public github repo. If you'd like to see actual examples of the aura framework in action in a living app, this might be of interest to you.